# MapsDemo not working + android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to get MapsDemo project that is shipped with Google add-ons to work. For that I got MD5 fingerprint of the default debug certificate and using that I generated MAPS API KEY and used it in the layout file.
In the manifest file I have added all the permissions that are required by it. My manifest file looks like

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

<application android:label="@string/activity_sample_code"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_sample_code" >

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

   <activity android:name="com.example.android.apis.MapsDemo" android:label="MapsDemo">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
        </intent-filter>
   </activity>

    <!-- ************************************* -->
    <!--      VIEW/WIDGET PACKAGE SAMPLES      -->
    <!-- ************************************* -->

    <activity android:name="com.example.android.apis.view.MapViewDemo" android:label="MapView">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.SAMPLE_CODE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.example.android.apis.view.MapViewCompassDemo" android:label="MapView and Compass">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.SAMPLE_CODE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

My maps layout file looks like

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="0msDghc7PL9izft4M7VdAxRREci8JIZeBEULPvw"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

But after all this, all I see is a blank gid screen. No maps are shown. Please help me in resolving this issue. What am i doing wrong here??

Comment: Have you ever solved this?  I am experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This I think google maps api v1 an it is already deprecated. It is now V2 visit https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/ for the api documentation.

Also you can try this quick start guide https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw

Enjoy. :-)